# How can I get a list of a Page's events?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to the FB graph and having trouble getting a collection of Events associated with a Page. Is there any way to get a list of all the events created by a Page?

I've tried these unsuccessfully:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&place=PAGE_ID`

This isn't a valid query.

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events`

Returns an empty set, I think because it's looking for events this Page is attending (rather than those it has created).

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events` is the correct way to get a list of events that was created by a page. You need a valid access token to return the events list for a page.

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer test this process.

I'm seeing a bug with events created after Monday, April 23 where all events are not being returned by a valid Graph API or FQL call. See this post for more info: [Graph API / FQL Does not return all events for a page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10336916/graph-api-fql-does-not-return-all-events-for-a-page)

I don't have bug creating privileges on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/. If you're seeing the same issue and can post a bug, please do so.

Comment: Thanks, never thought to try it on another Page's events list. It appears the https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events is the right one.

Comment: Does any one know why it doesn't work on this page? https://www.facebook.com/pages/La-CALLE-Jam-Sessions/404870736262643?id=404870736262643&sk=events

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Any idea how to do this nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer using the Javascript SDK

```
FB.api(
  '/{page-id}/events',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"timezone,cover,id,end_time,name,place,type,start_time,owner,event_times,description"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

Here I list events created by this page and for each event I want the timezone, the cover (image), the id, the start and end time, the place, the name, the description and the event's times